# Communicate from composable to fragment using viewmodel

Tags: android, fragment, kotlin-stateflow, composable

Communicate from composable to fragment using viewmodel

I am  having a Composable

```
@Composable
fun SimpleBottomButton(SCVM: StudioComposeViewModel) {
    Button(onClick = {
        SCVM.setbottomButtonClick(2)
    }) {
        Text(text = "Bottom Button")
    }
}
```

and a viewmodel

```
class ComposeViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
 private val _bottomButtonClick = MutableStateFlow(
        savedStateHandle["BottomButtonClick"] ?: 0
    )
    val bottomButtonClick
        get() =  _bottomButtonClick.asStateFlow()
    fun setbottomButtonClick(valuer: Int) {
        _bottomButtonClick.value = valuer
    }
```

}

in the fragment I want to get the data from viewmodel in a Fragment using this

```
 viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            SCVM.bottomButtonClick.flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect {
                    Log.e("bottomButtonClick",it.toString())

                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
        }
```

**However the data is not received**

Answer (score 0):

I think you will receive the first click event as your state flow changes its value from 0 to 2.
All the next events will not be emitted because `StateFlow` will not emit a new value if the new value is equal to its current value.

[See](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)

> Values in state flow are conflated using Any.equals comparison in a similar way to distinctUntilChanged operator.

Comment: but even the first click value of 2 is not received

Comment: I am trying to log the value in `fun setbottomButtonClick(valuer: Int)` and it is logged however it is not logged in fragment `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch`

Comment: Yes, your callback will still get an invocation. It's just a function. The problem is your state flow will not update, Because the updated value is equal with it's current value.

Comment: Can you log your current state-flow value in your `setbottomButtonClick` function?

Comment: `Can you log your current state-flow value in your setbottomButtonClick function?` yes

Comment: Post the log please

Comment: fun setBottomButtonClick(valuer: Int) {
        _bottomButtonClick.value = valuer
        Log.e("valuer",valuer.toString())
        Log.e("valuer bottomButtonVisibility",bottomButtonClick.value.toString())
    } this is the function and it displays  2023-03-29 12:03:32.263 30989-30989 valuer                  com.test.app                 E  2
2023-03-29 12:03:32.263 30989-30989 valuer bot...Visibility com.test.app                 E  2

Comment: Come on, you should log the value before you set it. After that, it's always `2` so your log makes no sense

Comment: will try as you sugest

Comment: this is the Log I get now 2023-03-29 16:04:48.577 29048-29048 before                  com.test.app                 E  0
2023-03-29 16:04:48.577 29048-29048 valuer                  com.test.app                 E  2
2023-03-29 16:04:48.578 29048-29048 valuer bot...Visibility com.test.app                 E  2

Comment: I have tried your code and it works. Where did you write the collector

Comment: Can i see your completely function where you register the collector

Comment: So can you tell me the root cause?

Comment: the problem is handling the click fun incrementCounter() {
        // Update state value based on some logic
       _counterState.value = _counterState.value + 1
        
    }